# Setting up Nginx for multiple domains

Tags: nginx

I've viewed a few previously posted questions similar to mine but none of them relate to my issue.

In my Nginx config I have the following set up:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name (www.)?domain1.com;
    root /etc/nginx/www/domain1.com;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name (www.)?domain2.com;
    root /etc/nginx/www/domain2.com;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

But both domains seem to point to /etc/nginx/www/domain2.com for some reason. What might I be doing incorrectly?

Comment: did you reload the service after making the change?

Comment: @shtuff.it I did, it didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: You have error in `server_name` directive. Regexp server names must be prefixed with `~`. But it would be much better to use `server_name domain1.com www.domain1.com;`

Comment: @AlexeyTen Fantastic. Can you make it an answer so I can select it as the best?

Comment: BTW, `fastcgi_split_path_info` is useless if you have such `try_files` directive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have error in `server_name` directive.

Regexp server names must be prefixed with `~`.

But it would be much better to use

```
server_name domain1.com www.domain1.com;
```

http://nginx.org/r/server_name